# Error when migrating efcore to version 3.1

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am getting error when migrating to efcore3.1

This line of code shows error :

```
 entity.HasOne(d => d.ContentControl)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Content)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ContentControlId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_Content_ContentControl");
```

Error :

> Error  CS7069  Reference to type 'ReferenceOwnershipBuilder<,>' claims it is defined in 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore', but it could not be found

how can i solve this?

Comment: What is error message? Please add this to the question too and also add your related model classes.

Comment: @TanvirArjel updated the error

Comment: Add your related model classes too and then explain what you are actually wanting.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't properly update all your dependencies? If you reference more than `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`, make sure to update versions of all of EF Cores assemblies, such as Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational etc. Also are you getting it while starting the application or while running dotnet commands such as `dotnet ef add migration xxx`? If later, do you have the latest .NET Core 3.1 SDK installed? (it ships with updated EF Core command line tools)

Comment: @Tseng the issue got resolved after updating the packagaes but now i am getting error in  public override Task Insert(ValuationPeriodState record, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            return _context.ValuationPeriodState.AddAsync(record, cancellationToken);
        }

Error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<T>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T>'

Comment: What the error message says :P New EF Core is using `ValueTask<T>` as return type to reduce allocations on tasks that compete synchronously. Your method either needs to return `ValueTask<T>` too or you `async`/`await` it. P.S. make sure to post a final answer with the steps that solved your issue for other readers who come here

Answer (score 1):

Probably missed to upgrade the dependent packges like Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLServer. Check that.